# Adding image to UIButton when hit

Tags: objective-c

Using `Xcode5` and storyBoard, i have a few `UIButtons`, with their images .
I need to add an image above a button when pressed , and to remove it also.
I know how to change the image of it, but i need to add image above it that stays there .

```
- (IBAction)color:(UIButton *)sender
{

     if(lastButton)
        //now remove a circle from last button  

    //add a circle to the image of the sender button 


     lastButton=sender;
}
```

Comment: Can you make this question bit more clear... Do  you want image for press state...? and when press release it should go back...? if you need this then u should set setImage for state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `UIButton` API:

```
if (lastButton) {
  [lastButton setImage:imageWithoutCircle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[sender setImage:imageWithCircle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
lastButton = sender;
```

Alternatively, you could have two image views, one without the circle, one with transparent background only containing the circle, and on top a transparent button. In your handler you could call

```
if (lastButton) {
    circleImageViewOfLastButton.hidden = no;
}
```

You could identify the correct circle view with the `tag` property, etc. But this would be more code than the original solution.

Comment: As i said in the question the goal is to add a circle above a selected button and not creating all my buttons again -with a circle ..